# How can get steam overlay information with python

Tags: python, overlay, steam

In steam game if we click ctrl + tab
We can get some game information from overlay.
And I wanna get Active Users information from overlay with python
[image]

Is there any way to get those informatin by using python?

I cant find in steam web api

Comment: some API may not give some information for security reason - because it could be used by spamers. OR maybe they didn't want to create this functionality. If API doesn't give this information then it big problem - the only idea to use module like `pyautogui` which can send to system pressed keys, make screenshot and then you can try to use OCR like `pytesseract` to recognize text on screen.

Comment: Nah thats not what I want. And there is discord bot called EOS that provide you those information

Comment: is those information accesible on some page ? then you could scrape it from page.

Comment: Im trying to find but I cant :(